# Match table relationship between team and player

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 tables **Entry** and **Match** if tournament team based **is_team=true** if player based **is_team=false**, so my question is how can I make a more effective match table, what would you suggest?
Thus i think that is not efficient for now.

Note: The reason I do this may not be the team of every player, so I just can't make the winner_team and team_a and team_b.

```
class Entry(models.Model): #Entries
tournament = 
player =
team =
is_team = 


class Match(models.Model):
entry_id = models.ForeignKey()
team_a = # if player based=null
team_b =
player_a = # if team based = null
player_b =
score_a =
score_b =
winner_team =   # if player based=null
winner_player = # if team based = null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [normalize your database](https://www.lifewire.com/database-normalization-basics-1019735) more. If you assume that a player by themselves is a team of 1, you can do the following:

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
    pass

class Team(models.Model):
    pass

class Player(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)

class TournamentTeam(models.Model):
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)

class Match(models.Model):
    # breaks normalization so you can keep track of newly created
    # matches in a tournament that don't have a winner or participants yet.
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament) 
    winner = models.ForeignKey(TournamentTeam, null=True, blank=True)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(TournamentTeam, through='MatchParticipant')


class MatchParticipant(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match)
    team = models.ForeignKey(TournamentTeam)
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: if player.team is null , then what should i do?

Comment: `player.team` will never be null. That was the constraint you'd need to accept to use the data model I'm proposing. A player by themselves is a team of 1.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try it.